# Flutter - Access a widget's variable from another script

Tags: flutter

I have the following StatefulWidget, and my goal is to access **'tags'** from another script:

```html
class MultiChoice<T extends Enum> extends StatefulWidget {
  List<T> tags = []; // what I want to access from another script/widget

  @override
  State<MultiChoice<T>> createState() => _MultiChoiceState<T>();
}
```

The thing is, I can't move 'tags' outside of my class, as it's generic, and I want the list to be of that type.

So what would be a good way of doing this?

Thanks!